# CSS Wildcard Selector - No override?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

Can anyone tell me why the last span is dotted? Why isn't it overwritten?

Forkable pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqjREd

```css
div div div * span {
  border: double;
}

div * * span {
  border: dotted;
}

div * {
  border: dashed;
}

div {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Line 1
  <br>
  <span>Line 2</span>
  <br>
  <div>
    Line 3
    <br>
    <span>Line 4</span>
    <br>
    <div>
      Line 5
      <br>
      <span>Line 6</span>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: **Specificity** I'd suggest you look it up - https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: What rule do you expect to overwrite it?

Comment: As an extension of  @Paulie_D's comment, see the [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) and the accompanying [w3 specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) documentaiton...

Comment: `div * * span` doesn't make much sense

Comment: @j08691: That matches a span that is at least a great-grandchild of a div. It's not something you'd often encounter in real-world CSS, that's for sure...

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down rule by rule.

Let's assume you've now heard of the term specificity, as others have alluded to in the comments. But let's assume either that you don't know anything about it beyond that it has something to do with your problem, or that you've read the links given to you but you're having trouble applying that knowledge to this specific problem.

To start, specificity only takes into account selectors that match the element to begin with. Since a `div` and a `span` are two different things, the last rule is irrelevant, so let's get rid of that:

```css
div div div * span {
  border: double;
}

div * * span {
  border: dotted;
}

div * {
  border: dashed;
}
```

Now we have three rules, two of which ask for a `span` specifically, and the third, any element.

The first rule, `div div div * span`, doesn't match the "Line 6" element, because its `div` ancestors only go up to three levels. There is no fourth level between the innermost `div` and the `span`, and the parent of the outermost `div` is not another `div`, but `body`. So the only two rules that actually match this element are:

```css
div * * span {
  border: dotted;
}

div * {
  border: dashed;
}
```

Now we can talk specificity. The universal selector `*` has zero specificity. All of your rules have only type selectors and/or universal selectors, so calculating their specificity is fairly straightforward:

```css
div * * span /* 2 types -> specificity = (0, 0, 2) */
div *        /* 1 type  -> specificity = (0, 0, 1) */
```

In conclusion, because the dotted border rule is more specific, the dashed border rule doesn't override it.